# Cocoa Array of Objects to String

Tags: iphone, cocoa, nsstring, nsmutablearray, separator

I have an NSMutableArray of objects.  Each object has a property called "Name".  I want to join them together in a string with a separator " > ".

So if the name property in each of the objects in my array is "one", "two" and "three" respectively, the result would be "one > two > three".

Thanks,
howie

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To get all the `name` properties, use [Key-Value Coding](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/index.html). Then you can just do `componentsJoinedByString:` to combine them all:

```
[[objects valueForKey:@"name"] componentsJoinedByString:@" > "]
```

Comment: +1 I love using `valueForKey:` on arrays.  It's so deliciously useful.